# Javascript IE8 not getting 'this' from attachEvent

Tags: javascript

This is a method of a larger class

```
myMethod.prototype.click=function(func){

 if (window.addEventListener) {
  this.selArray[i].addEventListener('click', func, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  this.selArray[i].attachEvent('onclick', func);
}


return this;

}
```

Which if I instigate passing this function....

```
myInstance.click(

    function () {
    alert(this.id)
    }
);
```

...alerts 'undefined' in IE 8 but returns the ID of the DOM object the click event is attached to in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, `attachEvent` doesn't quite work the way `addEventListener` does. You can do this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  this.selArray[i].addEventListener('click', func, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  this.selArray[i].attachEvent('onclick', func.bind(this.selArray[i]));
}
```

That uses `Function#bind` to ensure that `this` is the element on which you're hooking the event. You have have to shim/polyfill `Function#bind` on older browsers (like IE8), search for "es5 shim" for options.

Or if you don't want to use `Function#bind`, use a closure over the call to `click`:

```
myMethod.prototype.click=function(func){
    var elm = this.selArray[i];
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      elm.addEventListener('click', func, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      elm.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        return func.call(elm, e || window.event);
      });
    }

    return this;
}
```

Side note: Browsers that only supply `attachEvent` don't have `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` on the event object, either. A *thorough* shim (such as that in jQuery or PrototypeJS or various other libraries) adds those. The equivalent of `preventDefault` is `e.returnValue = false;`; the equivalent of `stopPropagation` is `e.cancelBubble = true;`.

Comment: Ok so IE8 & 9 wont need all this?

Comment: @user1209203: IE8 does. IE9 and up don't, because they provide `addEventListener`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I will probably leave IE8 users to upgrade their browser.

Comment: @user1209203: Up to you. I'd probably check your site stats, first, as the general stats say IE8 still has somewhere between 6% (statcounter) and 21% (net applications) of global browser users... As always, it's your *own* site's stats that matter, though. I mean, this is one of the most trivial browser differences to cope with... :-)